# Recaptcha enterprise - key for mobile - waiting for security review

Tags: recaptcha

we already have a reCAPTCHA Enterprise key for the web app.  Now we need to create a reCAPTCHA key for our mobile app.   We applied for security review many days ago... how long does it take for google to contact us and to perform a security review?   We need to launch our app very shortly, but still waiting for Google.

Thank you!